# Give advice for php xls eporter

Tags: php, excel, export

Hi I tried using PHPExport(codeplex) library but it has memory issues and it won't work for me. I need to export a relatively big xls file (~4 sheets 30X300).  I found topics in the forum that suggest PHPExport alternatives but I can't find any information if they support cell text-alignment, setting borders, setting cell type, cell width/roll etc. Also if they'd be able to handle that big table. I read a lot people took the decision to export their big tables in csv but does it support cell styling. I believe this is not a duplicate to any posted question so I'd appreciate any advice. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which of the PHPExcel memory saving options have you tried? 4 sheets of 30x300 is relatively small

Comment: I will research these "memory saving options" and write again

Comment: I tried running this code -> http://pastebin.com/1yjDABBk It sets about half of the cell's background to blue (when i should set all). I send the script to a friend and it worked correctly at his computer... What could that be...

Comment: I don't know, but I'd recommend setting style for the range of cells, not for every individual cell `$worsheet->getStyle('A1:J10')->getFill()
->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
->getStartColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_BLUE);`

Answer (score 0):

I am using this one : https://www.manjeshojha.com/how-to-import-the-excel-data-in-mysql-database-using-php-script/

Working fine for me..Try tour self once..